# Can client use BoringSSL to talk to server that uses OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl, boringssl

I have a server/client program that uses OpenSSL for secured communication. For some reason I have to use BoringSSL on the client side and prefer to keep OpenSSL on server side.

I am able to compile BoringSSL to libssl.a/libcrypto.a and link to client program, only issue is when using `SSL_CTX_new()` to initiate a SSL connection, only function `TLS_with_buffers_method()` is available. On the server side I am using `TLS_server_method()` in `SSL_CTX_new()` when creating a counterpart connection. In this case client fails to initiate a SSL connection to server.

Just want to confirm is there a way to configure BoringSSL to work with OpenSSL? Or it doesn't work because the detailed implementation underneath is different...

My server is a linux host while client is an android/ios host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both BoringSSL and OpenSSL implement the TLS standards which are designed to be interoperable. There should be no problem with a BoringSSL client connecting to an OpenSSL server.

Comment: Thanks. That being said, do you know which server function from openssl should I use if I am using `TLS_with_buffers_method()` or `DTS_with_buffers_method()` in client with BoringSSL?  I have tried `TLS_method()` and `TLS_server_method()` on linus side but didn't work

Comment: I'm not familiar with the BoringSSL API differences so can't advise on that side of things. However TLS_method() or TLS_server_method() should be just fine on the OpenSSL side. These are the recommended methods.